# BREW ERROR : compinit:503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_cask

Tags: macos, iterm

I recently got this error:

```
compinit:503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_cask
```

I didn't install anything new. I just updated the brew using "brew update" command. The next time I updated the terminal my Oh-My-Zsh theme was gone. So I checked the `ZSH_THEME` variable and it was properly set. I restarted my MacBook and found that my theme came back to normal but I still get the same **compinit** error whenever I try to run the source command.

I uninstalled and reinstalled Homebrew but still the same problem. What should I do?

---

**UPDATE(Solved)**:

I found out that it was an issue with the symlinks.

I used the following command `brew cleanup` and the problem was solved.

Comment: A similar question was posted on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/65747286/7451909), where the current top-rated answer suggests simply running `brew cleanup`. Does that fix things?

Answer (score 4):

```
brew cleanup
```

Run this command :)

Comment: It annoyed me so much, thank you

Comment: you're welcome :) glad it helped!