# speedtest-cli Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/speedtest

Tags: macos

I was using Ookla's speedtest-cli command line app just fine until recently when it started giving me an error: "ImportError: No module named speedtest". After a copious amount of research it led me to upgrade system files by doing a forced MACOS software update. Now the error when running speedtest-cli is **Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/speedtest**

The folder is indeed there. Confirmation:

```
ls /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/speedtest
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/speedtest
```

Steps to install speedtest-cli were followed to the letter from [Ookla's website](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli)

Steps to reproduce (with error):

```
MyMAC:Source_Code me$ brew tap teamookla/speedtest
MyMAC:Source_Code me$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
MyMAC:Source_Code me$ brew install speedtest --force
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/speedtest
MyMAC:Source_Code me$
```

I have already tried to remove speedtest (brew uninstall speedtest --force) and re-install but with no success.

Comment: Could this perhaps be caused by access restrictions put on the terminal application? I can't recall exactly when, but as a security measure, Apple restricted applications' access to the filesystem and you need to explicitly allow your terminal to access certain folders. Try `cd`-ing to the folder and, if you can't, try granting permissions in `System preferences`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I granted read+write access to every folder starting from var down to speedtest but it made no difference. I do agree that it's a MACOS thing rather than the speedtest utility.

Comment: Well, I found similar issue someone was having (although not with speedtest-cli)and they suggested issuing the command "brew cleanup". I'm now able to install speedtest-cli with no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar issue someone was having (although not with speedtest-cli) and they suggested issuing the command `brew cleanup`. I'm now able to install speedtest-cli with no issue. Solution was found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632554/brew-error-compinit503-no-such-file-or-directory-usr-local-share-zsh-site?rq=1).